# How to get progress of sending image via bluetooth (Gamekit)?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, gamekit

I implement an application on iPhone which sharing photo via bluetooth(Gamekit).

I want to khow how to get a percentage of photo sending.

Please tell me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To keep under the maximum transferred data size you have to support breaking up your data.

Break up your data in, say, 10 fragments. Send each fragment in turn. Add up the percentages as each fragment is sent and recieved.

Alternatively have the recipient post back unreliably how much data has been received.